# How to show a title and description in one page by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, flip

Hi how to make title and description in same page by jquery. Like this http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/its/projects/ when click on the each project name the description will open bellow it and click another one the previous open div will close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/tTD4D/

API used: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Or like the Zoltan mentioned : http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

This should fit your need `:)`

**code**

```
$(".title").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $content = $this.next(".content");
    if (!$content.is(":visible")) {
        $(".content:visible").slideToggle(100);
        $content.slideToggle(500);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Ok. Its an example of div. How can it possible by table like one table 2 row when click on any odd no row the next even no row will open.

Comment: @RafiurRabby Hiya, Cool, yep we will fix it, flick me your code in fiddle I will take a look man `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basics

```
$('.title').on('click', function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
   } else {
      $('.title').removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
   }
});
```

Html would be something like this

```
<div class="title">
  title here to be clicked
  <p class="desc">blah</p>
</div>
```

the css maybe something like this

```
.title p {
   display: none
}

.title.open p {
   display:block
}
```

sliding effects or whatnot is just icing on the cake, that stuff you can google